# How can I change a form field value before saving to db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, action

I have form:

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :date %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :repeat %><br />
    <%= repeat_types = ['none', 'daily', 'monthly', 'yearly'] 
        f.select :repeat, repeat_types %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I need save into 'repeat' field changed data as:

```
:repeat = Event.rule(:date,:repeat)
```

Where and how can I modify the repeat field before saving it to database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if you need to change data slightly from what the user entered in a form before saving it to the database, you can do so in Rails by using [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) such as `before_save`. For example, you might have the following:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_repeat

  private
  def set_repeat
    self.repeat = Event.rule(date, repeat) if ['none', 'daily', 'monthly', 'yearly'].include? repeat
  end
end
```

This would always run the `set_repeat` private callback method on an `Event` instance before saving it to the DB, and changes the `repeat` attribute if it is currently one of the strings in `['none', 'daily', 'monthly', 'yearly']` (but you should adjust this logic as needed -- I just guessed at what you might want).

So I would look into [ActiveRecord callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks) as a general way to modify model attributes before saving them.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I could use an ActiveRecords callback in my Event model. As follows:

```
  before_save do
    self.repeat = Event.rule(self.date, self.repeat )
  end
```

Comment: What does `Event.repeat` return? Should that not be `self.repeat`?